# how to commit changes of angular 4 to git pages via git bash

Tags: angular, github, github-pages, git-bash

I have already starting a new project with Angular 4. I try to deploy the build project to git pages and successfully deployed. But my problem is how to commit changes to deploy the changes in git pages. I follow the steps to deploy the project to git and git pages

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit
git remote add origin git@github.com:{myusername}/MyNewAngularApp.git
git push -u origin master
ng build --prod --aot --base-href https://nahidhasanswe.github.io/mynewangularapp/
ngh
```

Now please tell me how to commit changes to git pages

Thank You

Comment: You probably should dig into the git documentation, e.g. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout gh-pages
git merge master
git push origin gh-pages
```

This should work!